# System.StackOverflowException when switching between forms

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I am trying to create a menu for a game I' m developing. This is the source code:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Racing_Manager
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Exit Button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    //Help Button
    private void Help_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Play Button
    private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        Form2 secondMenu = new Form2();
        secondMenu.Show();

    }
    }
    }
```

Then I have:

```
namespace Racing_Manager
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Back Button
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();

    }
    }
    }
```

When I run this, it gives a System.StackOverflowException (I know, quite appropriate) on this line:

```
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it? Anything I can do to improve the code quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer state, Form1 and Form2 both create an instance of themselves when a new instance is constructed. It looks like you want a singleton. To achieve this change your code like so

```
//From
public Form1 = new Form1()
//To
public static Form1 = new Form1();
```

This will create an instance of the Form as soon as the Form1 **class** is referenced for the first time. So Form1.Form1 would automatically create a single instance.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. However, when I am switching between forms, the first one closes, you think the app crashed, but then the other form appears. How do I solve this?

Comment: Accept my answer, then post your code in a new question and post a link in these comments.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is in the first lines:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

What should this line do?

When you create an instance of `Form1` it's members are initialized. Here you declared a member `form1` that is initialized by creating a new instance of `Form1`.

When you create an instance of `Form1` it's members are initialized. Here you declared a member `form1` that is initialized by creating a new instance of `Form1`.

When you create an instance of `Form1` it's members are initialized. Here you declared a member `form1` that is initialized by *creating a new instance of `Form1`*.

When you create an instance of `Form1` it's members are initialized. Here you declared a member `form1` that is initialized by **creating a new instance of `Form1`**.

When you create an instance of `Form1` it's members are initialized. Here you declared a member `form1` that is initialized by **CREATING A NEW INSTANCE OF `Form1`.**

> StackOverflowException

because you recursivly call the constructor of `Form1` and so your call stack eventually runs full.

The same goes for `Form2`.

---

Conclusion: remove this line from your `Form1` class (and the one from `Form2`), you don't need it anyway.

Comment: the same is applicable to `Form2`!

Comment: @klappvisor yep, forgot to add that, did it now.

Comment: **Warning**: this answer may throw a StackOverflowException if the OP continues to initialize instances of Form1.

Answer (score 2):

It's the *very first line* that's wrong:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Form1 form1 = new Form1(); // <- this one
```

You're creating `Form1` instance, but `Form1` should initialize `Form1 form1` field, which in turn creates `Form1` instance with its own `Form1 form1` to be initialized...

Comment: That, to me, sounds like the second line.

Answer (score 1):

You have a property `Form1` inside your `Form1` class. It cause an infinite loop.

So you should change :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }...
```

to

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{  
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }...
```